# Using setTimeoutwith req, and res

Tags: node.js, express, settimeout

I want to make it so when i press a button, it will trigger an app.post. This will make a sql select from happen. If the select from returns a certain value, i want the code not to run. I have made all the code for that, but i need a setTimeout. I cant use setTimeout because it doesnt let me use req and res.
Here is a little sample.

```
app.post('/home, (req, res) => {
con.query('SELECT * FROM table', (result) => {
check = result;
});
//setTimeout starts here 
var checker = check.includes('Hello');
if (checker == true) {
console.log(1);
} else {
console.log(0)
}
//setTimeout ends here with a  delay of 30
});
```

Is there any way to do this with node.js and express.

Comment: You have an asynchronous problem, because `check` can never be filled before you read from it. You also don't show your setTimeout and I for one have no clue what you want it to do. At best, you'll have a race condition. Most likely you could just put everything you need in the callback of your query instead of doing weird shenanigans with `setTimeout`.

Comment: sorry i messed up some of the code. I need instead of 'console.log(0)" i need to put res.sendFile(__dirname + '/homepage.html')